# How does nginx load balances node instances

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have 3 cpu cores on my machine, and I have 3 instances of node running, one for each core. When I access such server directly, that's a master process that always gets called. However, when I use a reversed nginx proxy, the process is random. Where does nginx chooses which node process to run?

```
http://domain.com:1000 -> proxy
http://domain.com:2000 -> node processes
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 1000;

    server_name node;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain.com:2000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/#method

Comment: Yes, but here load balancing is used for different ports (servers). In my case nginx balances multiple processes on the same port.

Comment: Nginx can only load balance across multiple back ends. It has no knowledge of a Node Cluster. The question you might be asking is "Why is my Node Cluster responding differently to nginx compared to when I access it directly". If so include your clustering code. I suspect the answer will be your browser keeping the tcp connection alive when going direct.

Comment: btw node clusters also round robin by default. https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#cluster_how_it_works

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has no knowledge of your back-end's clustering the way you've configured it. As noted in a comment against your original question, Nginx load balancing only applies if you configure it with multiple backends. You are not doing this.

Therefore, if your backend itself is something like NodeJS using the Cluster module, the load balancing is happening there. Node doesn't need any "help" from Nginx to do this - it has its own mechanisms. They're described in https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works:

> The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming connections.
>
> The first one (and the default one on all platforms except Windows), is the round-robin approach, where the master process listens on a port, accepts new connections and distributes them across the workers in a round-robin fashion, with some built-in smarts to avoid overloading a worker process.
>
> The second approach is where the master process creates the listen socket and sends it to interested workers. The workers then accept incoming connections directly.

You can therefore choose how you want this to work in your Node back-end. At the moment, you are telling Nginx to always go to port 2000, therefore whatever you have running there is getting the traffic. If that is the master process for a Node Cluster, it will round-robin load balance. If that is one of the child workers, then that child worker will get ALL the traffic and the others will get none.